# how to Folter password protection using .htaccess and .htpasswd?

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

This my path: http://172.21.4.100/bluescope_app/index.php?page=creer_contact_client

I have two files:

1<sup>st</sup>: `.htpasswd` holds only:

> dave:`***password***`

2<sup>nd</sup>: `.htaccess` holds:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /172.21.4.100/bluescope_app/dave/.htpasswd  //<---- I'm stuck here, is this correct ?

AuthName "Enter valid username and password!"

<Files test.php>
    require valid-user
</Files>
```

On browser I got prompt but I can't access with my password.

If you know the answer Post as much as possible, thank you.

Included path:

http://172.21.4.100/bluescope_app/.htaccess

http://172.21.4.100/bluescope_app/.htpasswd

Answer (score 0):

AuthUserFile  should include the absolute path not URL

To get the absolute path, you can do this in php :

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

It will return something like

```
/home/user98/www/public_html/
```

So in that case, since your .htpasswd is in the directory `bluescope_app/dave`

You should do :

```
AuthUserFile /home/user98/www/public_html/bluescope_app/dave/.htpasswd
```

This in an example on linux, if you are on windows it will be almost the same...

Answer (score 0):

I got answer ,
I used Double Quotes then i got ,,

```
AuthUserFile "/var/www/html/bluescope_app/dave/.htpasswd"
```

thanks for your idea (use absolute path)@Dany Khalife